# Do the ec2 instances that have attached SSD loose SSD data after termination?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

For EC2 instances that have attached SSD (not EBS) ([Storage optimized instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/storage-optimized-instances.html)), will they lose the data stored in those SSDs after termination?

Comment: Do you mean EC2 *instances*? Where should the data go instead??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see the term "**instance storage**", it refers to disks that are **directly attached to the host computer**.

When an instance is Stopped or Terminated, the host computer is no longer used. Therefore, the contents of the disks is lost.

Therefore, they should only be used to store data for activities such as:

- Temporary processing
- Caching of data
- Where the data is stored permanently elsewhere

The benefit of Instance Storage is that it is *very* fast and offers low-latency access.

If you want the data on the disks to be maintained after an instance is Stopped or Terminated, then store your data on Amazon EBS volumes.

Also, please note that both Instance Storage and Amazon EBS volumes use SSD (amongst other storage technologies).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, instance store volume data is lost on instance termination. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html):

> The data on an instance store volume persists even if the instance is rebooted. However, the data does not persist if the instance is stopped, hibernated, or terminated. When the instance is stopped, hibernated, or terminated, every block of the instance store volume is cryptographically erased.